# Fluid Design bugs in ie7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, fluid, css

I've created a dummy layout for my latest design, but when I resize the window in ie7 to check that the min-width works, it kicks the content area to below the sidebar, whereas in all other browsers (including ie6) it behaves exactly as it should do.

[Demo Link](http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/control/test/)

Can anyone see what the problem is that's causing this random couple extra pixels that kick it off?

Comment: Comparison screenshots in IE: http://browsershots.org/http://qwibbledesigns.co.uk/preview/control/test/ (still queued at time of writing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there does seem to be a bug in IE where the `min-width` elements are getting float-like clearing behaviour.

You can easily avoid it in this case by applying the `min-width` to the `#container` instead of both the child elements. (It is in general best to put layout-related `min-width` fixes on the highest possible parent element.)

(Also, you don't need the float-100%-width rules on the bar/content.)